# Joining Values Of Two Columns From DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

**Joining Values Of Two Columns From DataTable** 
Two columns make it in one columns from datatable

my datatable is

```
   TagNumber, LogNumber  Combined
    124           1         2
    125           1         3
    126           2         4
o/p:

     TagNumber 
    124 ~1~2          
    125 ~1~3         
    126 ~2~4         
 combined column is merge from column0 and column1
```

i dont understand hw can i do please write sample of code

I dont have experience on linq .
I add column bt hw can i merge two columns in that one columns

```
I got answer:

For i As Integer = 0 To dstemp.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
dstemp.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0) = dstemp.Tables(0).Rows(i)("TagNumber") & "~" &      dstemp.Tables(0).Rows(i)("LogNumber") & "~" & dstemp.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Combined")
next
```

Comment: i dont understand hw can i do please write sample of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok if you really want to do this then you have create a extra DataTable with Three Columns:

**TagNumber, LogNumber  Combined**:
as below:

```
private DataTable CreateDataTableColumns()
{
    DataTable dtThreeItems = new DataTable();
    dtThreeItems.Columns.Add("TagNumber", typeof(String));
    dtThreeItems.Columns.Add("LogNumber", typeof(String));
    dtThreeItems.Columns.Add("Combined", typeof(String));
    return dtThreeItems;
}
```

Now iterate the old datatable as below to get combined value:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtTwoItems.Rows)
            {
                row = dtThreeItems.NewRow();
                row["TagNumber"] = dr["TagNumber"].ToString();
                row["LogNumber"] = dr["LogNumber"].ToString();
                row["Combined"] = dr["TagNumber"].ToString()+"/"+dr["LogNumber"].ToString() ;
                dtThreeItems.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Thats All

Comment: but my datatable hv not fixed columns its change according search so hw can merge in existing table

Answer (score 12):

Try doing it like this.

```
 dtTwoItems.Columns.Add("Combined", typeof(string), "TagNumber+'/'+LogNumber");
```

Comment: This is actually the proper way of doing it. Iterating through each row is less efficient and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to Add new Column to DataTable and then iterate through Each Row to put value by combining them?

EDIT: I Am not sure if Linq or Datatable query have some inbuilt feature to do this, but simple solution is what I tell. Or if you are filling your datatable from any SQL Query based database, then write a SQL that has third column with merged value using concat of columns.

Edit2:

```
foreach (Datarow r in myTable.Rows) {
   r["Newcolumn"] = Convert.ToString(r["c1"]) + "/" + Convert.ToString(r["c2"]);
}
```

Comment: I add column bt hw can i merge two columns in that one columns

Comment: how can use dattable.merge

Comment: guptaji hw can merge it in one column

Comment: guptaji it gives error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: Not sure what you want to merge, in loop we already merge it up. It is too simple to explain.

Comment: wt simple guptaji try to understand my problem

Answer (score 1):

DataTable is like a container.
It is not proper to join tables.

I recommend you'd use linq.

Comment: I dont have experience on linq

Comment: Sumit Gupta it gives error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.