# How to merge two columns from a datatable and make it single column using select and CopyToDataTable functions

Tags: c#

I am reading CSV file into datatable.

In my datatable I have 4 columns date, time, value1 and value2.

```
Date           Time         VALUE1           VALUE2    
05/16/2019     15:08:02     2.01             1.01    
05/16/2019     15:08:03     4.02             1.02    
05/16/2019     15:08:04     5.03             1.03
```

I want to merge date and time columns  in the datatable into a single column called datetime and need to merge date and time values with comma.

I want like below.

```
DateTime                  VALUE1           VALUE2    
05/16/2019,15:08:02       2.01             1.01    
05/16/2019,15:08:03       4.02             1.02    
05/16/2019,15:08:04       5.03             1.03
```

How to achieve it?

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining Values Of Two Columns From DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140445/joining-values-of-two-columns-from-datatable)

Comment: You can do this by creating a new column and writing a simple update query. Did you try any thing?

Comment: @Chetan, I created new datatable and added values from old datatble by iterating but  I want simple solution.

Comment: @Chetan, could you please provide code snippet for how to use update query with c# datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare one more temporary table to hold columns in table and then by using `.Select` predicate in linq you can flatten your existing datable rows to newly created table with `.CopyToDataTable()` extension.

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
_dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("VALUE1", typeof(double));
_dt.Columns.Add("VALUE2", typeof(double));


DataTable result = dt.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(x =>
     {
         var r = _dt.NewRow();

         r["DateTime"] = Convert.ToString(x["Date"]) + ", " + Convert.ToString(x["Time"]);
         r["VALUE1"] = Convert.ToDouble(x["VALUE1"]);
         r["VALUE2"] = Convert.ToDouble(x["VALUE2"]);

         return r;
     })
     .CopyToDataTable();
```

In the above code snippet `result` is a data table that contains flattened output from above LINQ query.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I have a doubt. As per my understanding, in your code  dt is new table and where you are copying from old datatable

Comment: no `dt` is your existing datatable where your data exist in it and `_dt` is new datatable that holds column for flattened result from `.Select` linq predicate

Comment: one doubt, why new datatable _dt is not having any data but the result datatable is having data.

Comment: `_dt` is only for holding new columns like DateTime, Value1, and Value2 and CopyToDataTable extension flatten these columns to result datatable, got it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
dt.Columns.Add("DateTime_Merge", typeof(string), "Date+','+Time");
```

For removing `columns`

```
dt.Columns.Remove("Date");
dt.Columns.Remove("Time");
```

Comment: I want simple solution. Can I get any solution using datatable select function and CopyToDataTable() function?

Comment: For me Datetime column should be the first column

Comment: `dt.Columns["DateTime_Merge"].SetOrdinal(0);`

Comment: how to update values in the table.How to add values to the DateTime_Merge column in the table.

Comment: @userrmgs, Just run the above and see the datatable, It will have the result as u expected....

Comment: when I tried your code I got this exception "Cannot remove this column, because it is part of an expression: DateTime = Date+','+Time."

Comment: okay, `dt` datatable DateTime_Merge column has data with the combination??

Comment: I have already asked this doubt  of how to update values in the table.How to add values to the DateTime_Merge column in the table